# pattern matching in result of subquery

Tags: postgresql, subquery, pattern-matching

I have three tables namely `ordrer` , `campaign_company` and `kontaktperson`

I have following query, there is a selger alias for subquery and wants to having pattern matching over it -

```
select 
    (select ordredato from ordrer where kundenr = campaign_company.kunder_id  order by ordredato desc limit 1) 
        as last_contract, 
    (select 
        (select fornavn || ' ' || etternavn from kontaktperson where ordrer.kpkode=kontaktperson.kpkode) 
        from ordrer 
        where kundenr = campaign_company.kunder_id 
     order by ordredato desc limit 1) 
        as selger  
from ordrer 
     left join campaign_company on campaign_company.sale = ordrenr 
// i tried with having to 
where 
    selger like '%string%'
```

but gives an error selger column not found

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your query:

```
SELECT * FROM (<your select>) AS a WHERE selger like '%string%'
```

Or you can modify query:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT
    FIRST(o2.ordredato) OVER (ORDER BY o2.ordredato) AS last_contract,
    FIRST(k.fornavn || ' ' || k.etternavn) OVER (ORDER BY o2.ordredato)as selger
FROM 
    order AS o
    LEFT JOIN campaign_company ASD cc ON (cc.sale = o.ordrenr) 
    LEFT JOIN order AS o2 ON (o2.kundenr = cc.kunder_id)
    LEFT JOIN kontaktperson AS k ON (o2.kpkode = k.kpkode)
) AS a
WHERE selger like '%string%'
```